# Docker not hosting anything on the port it says it is, what's going on?

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core, servicestack

I am working through [this blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExploringServiceStacksSimpleAndFastWebServicesOnNETCore.aspx) which explains how to host a sample ServiceStack app on .net core via Docker.

In the command line I see:

> Now listening on: https://*:5000

But as shown in the below screenshot, nothing seems to be hosted on localhost port 5000.

[image: Docker not hosting anything]

I have tried this on my Mac and PC and it's the same result.

I am brand new to Docker so I'm assuming this something obvious on my part so apologies for the noob question!

Thanks

Comment: Did you open and redirect a port from the container to your app? By default, apps running in the container can't be reached from outside it, unless you add port mapping to route a outside port to a port inside the container (similar to how NAT works)

Comment: @Tseng nope, brand new to Docker, can you link to a resource showing how to do this? Thanks

Comment: `-P outsideport:innerport`, i.e. `-P 443:5000`, then you'd connect with `https://localhost/` to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default docker containers do not expose any ports to the world outside of the container. When you start a container, you need to add a port mapping similar to NAT so it can be reached form outside ([docs](http://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/)).

When you run `docker run` you need to pass the port mappings via `-p IP:host_port:container_port` parameter, i.e. `docker run -p 443:5000`. Then connect to it via `https://localhost` (https is on port 443).

Comment: I get what you are saying, however this isn't working for me either. The CLI isn't complaining about the *-p*  argument, but still can't connect via the browser. Any thoughts?

Comment: Not sure how docker is implemented on windows, but for the low ports (ports <= 1024), one requires administrative privileges. If unsure, try it with a higher port or run the powershell as admin

Comment: Alternatively execute `netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:80 user=DOMAIN\username` as Administrator, this adds the permission to the given user to bind to ports <= 1024 w/o administrative priviledges

Comment: Still no joy unfortunately @Tseng, either on Windows or Mac OS, very odd!